# How can I call the function in this class properly?

Tags: python-2.7, class, self

My question is how I can call my printDistance function in my City class properly, by inputting two city names available in a CSV I read in. I intend to use values associated with those two cities to perform an equation.

But when I input two cities (Paris and Tokyo) to test, I receive `"NameError: name 'Paris' is not defined."` I'm trying to have `self` and `othercity` be able to identify the city I input.

```
class City:
    def __init__ (self, name, label, lat, lon, pop_dict):
        self.name = name
        self.label = label
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.pop_dict = pop_dict
        lat1 = float(lat_self)
        lat2 = float(lat_othercity)
        lon1 = float(lon_self)
        lon2 = float(lon_othercity)
        radian_lat1 = math.radians(lat1)
        radian_lat2 = math.radians(lat2)
        radian_lon1 = math.radians(lon1)
        radian_lon2 = math.radians(lon2)
        AD = (math.acos(math.sin(radian_lat1) * math.sin(radian_lat2) + math.cos(radian_lat1) * math.cos(radian_lat2) * math.cos(radian_lon1 - radian_lon2)))
        print "The distance between", self, "and", othercity, "is", int((AD * 6300)), "kilometers."

    @classmethod 
    def printDistance(self, othercity):     
        lat_self = self.lat
        lat_othercity = othercity.lat
        lon_self = self.lon
        lon_othercity = othercity.lon

Cities = []

f = open("CityPop.csv","r")
header = f.readline()
header = header.strip().split(",")
for line in f:
    record = line.strip().split(",")
    pop = {}
    for i in range (5, 14):
        pop[header[i]] = record[i]
    newCity = City(name = record[3], label = record[4], lat = record[1], lon = record[2], pop_dict = pop)
    Cities.append(newCity)


print City.printDistance(Paris, Tokyo) #example
```

Comment: You need `City` objects: `Cities[0].printDistance(Cities[1])`. You might want a helper function such as: `Paris = findCity("Paris")` to find a `City` object in the array with that name.

Comment: Although, it won't print much since `printDistance` doesn't print or return anything.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you, will try this now. And for the sake of shorter code, I removed the actual returned equation portion of the function.